# Why Iran does not sell drones to Ukraine instead?

Tags: ukraine, iran

Iran provides Shahed-136 drones to Russia, to launch them into Ukraine. This way, Iran obviously gets into friction with the EU, the US, and other world powers that are standing on Ukraine's side.

Ukraine likely also has money and needs cheap drones. Why would Iran risk conflict with/sactions from the EU and US by supplying Shaheeds for Russia? Why not sell them to Ukraine instead as Turkey does? Even if for some reason Ukraine finds no use for them, buying all the drones and simply trashing them still seems cheaper than shooting them down later.

Is it that this war means something to Iran, and they are seeking more than just money by making and selling weapons to Russia?

Comment: Ukraine is curently big friends with the USA, and for Iran, USA is the Devil Incarnate. Perhaps that's why.

Comment: I doubt Ukraine has the money to actually pay for drones. All their other weapons are gifts.

Comment: Lithuanians, Poles collected money for Bayraktars for Ukraine. If Iranian drones are cheaper and also good, why not?

Comment: I think Ukrainians prefer [Warmates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WB_Electronics_Warmate) and [Fly Eyes](https://www.army-technology.com/projects/fly-eye-unmanned-aerial-vehicle/)

Comment: The EU has issued new sanctions over the drone sales. https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/10/20/eu-agrees-new-sanctions-over-iranian-drones-in-ukraine

Comment: Why should they sell to Ukraine?

Comment: It is like a good sword master from whom all fighting sides buy swords because these are just very good.

Comment: I don't think Iran betrays Russia. Furthermore, Iran became hostile to Ukraine since the PS752 shootdown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the Iranian government seems to be reluctant to even admit that they are doing it, not to speak of explaining why they are doing it, we can only resort to (hopefully) reasoned speculation.

First, I don't think the "selling drones to Russia incurs the wrath of the EU/US"-argument is particularly strong here. Iran already has a heavy bunch of sanctions slapped on them anyway. In fact, I have no seen any reports of new sanctions being discussed in this context - the screws may already be as tight as they get.

Second, it is not clear to me that buying Iranian drones would be a feasible option for Ukraine. A lot of the money Ukraine uses to buy weapons comes from the US and the EU. I really don't see the US tolerating Ukraine using US subsidies to pay Iran; and the EU wouldn't be happy with that either. Of course Ukraine could try "We're not paying Iran with the money we got from you, but with this other money we got from taxes/crowd funding/etc" as an argument. But it does seem risky to potentially annoy significant supporters in this way.

Third, there may just be some "the enemy of the friend of my enemy is my friend" Cold War-style logic going on. The Iranian government hates the US, so if the US gives weapons to Ukraine, giving weapons to Russia may feel appropriate. Side benefits are getting real-life data on how well or not the drones operate against a wide range of Western air defences. (With accompanying downside: The West learns how well their stuff works against Iranian drones. We may see Gepards being put back into use or so.)

Fourth, there is more than money Russia can offer. A Russian-Iranian alliance all but eliminates the risk of the UN Security Council passing anything against Iran. Depending on just how desperate Russia is, there might even be some nuclear technology on the negotiating table.

Comment: To add to this - while US and Europe have placed economic sanctions on Iran, Russia has cultivated a friendly relation with Iran over the same period including selling them weapons and investing in Iran.

Comment: The fourth is IMO the most important. It's not about getting money for drones, it's about getting an ally. Russia can also offer some technology ignoring sanctions on Iran. Ukraine will not.

Comment: As follow up to the first point about already having sanctions in place, is it possible that those existing sanctions are preventing Ukraine from buying drones from Iran? Do we have any reason to believe that they didn't try to sell drones to both sides and just couldn't get it done?

Comment: @JoeW Trying to sell weapons to both Ukraine and Russia would be political suicide for Iran, as Russia would never accept that and even become openly hostile to Iran. Iran just doesn't have the political space to do such a thing.

Comment: @sfxedit And I am suggesting that it isn't even a possibility because the current sanctions on Iran prevent Ukraine from purchasing them in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure about firs paragraph of your post? SEE this : https://en.irna.ir/news/84933185/Drone-delivery-dates-back-to-months-before-Ukraine-war-Iran

Comment: They did put some extra sanctions: https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/3/21/us-targets-iranian-drones-in-latest-round-of-sanctions Even the EU did: https://iranprimer.usip.org/blog/2023/feb/27/eu-sanctions-iran-providing-drones-russia Although the latter ones were seemingly after you posted this. In fact, the US has even sanctioned Chinese companies for providing parts https://www.rferl.org/a/iran-us-sanctions-drone-program-pasna/32370877.html

Comment: Although according to an Israeli analysis, this is likely to be rather ineffective, given the widespread use of shell companies https://www.jpost.com/international/article-739754 (Guess what Israel does instead ... https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/iran-drone-attack-military-factory-israel-tensions-rcna68114